# Passing variables from HTML to ActionScript

Tags: html, actionscript-3

I'm trying to send variables from my WebPage to a Flash object. But it doesn't work.

Here is the way I call the animation inside the webpage :

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/flash/Reintegrate.swf" width="1150" height="800" value="idu=Salut"></object>
```

Here is my code in AS3, LblTst shows nothing :

```
var userid:String = loaderInfo.parameters.idu;
LblTst.text = userid;
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this between the `<object>` tag :

```
...><param name="flashvars" value="idu=Salut"/></object>
```

Comment: @Bahaïka instead of  `loaderInfo.parameters.idu` use `root.loaderInfo.parameters.idu`